# convergence of $\int^\infty_0 x^2.e^{-ax} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, exponential-function

I have to check convergence or divergence of $\int^\infty_0 x^2.e^{-ax} dx$ .

I am following the basic approach of solving such improper integrals and used:

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\int^p_0x^2.e^{-ax}.dx$$

I have managed to crack it down to:

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}-\left|\frac{x^2.e^{-ax}}{a}+\frac{2xe^{-ax}}{a^2}+\frac{2e^{-ax}}{a^3}\right|^b_0$$

Now, funny thing is. It gives me:
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}-e^{-ab}\left[\frac{b^2}{a}+\frac{2b}{a^2}+\frac{2}{a^3}\right]+\frac{2}{a^3}$$

So, basically, it deduces to:
$$(\to\infty)\times(\to0)+\frac{2}{a^3}$$

My book says that answer is convergent with integral reducing to $\frac{2}{a^3}$ But I don't see how.

Please help.

Comment: The exponential term goes to zero faster than the rational / polynomial term.  If you don't like the handwave, hit it with L'Hospital's rule (the denominator will be $-e^{ab}$).

Comment: It diverges unless $a>0.$ Where did you say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First $x^2.e^{-ax}=\mathcal{O}(x^{-2})\implies \int^\infty_0 x^2.e^{-ax} dx\quad$ converges

$\begin{array}{l}\displaystyle \int x^2.e^{-ax} dx&=\displaystyle\left[-x^2\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]+\int2x\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\;dx\\&=\displaystyle \displaystyle\left[-x^2\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]+\dfrac{2}{a}\left(\left[-x\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]+\dfrac{1}{a}\int e^{-ax}\;dx\right)\\
&= \left[-x^2\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]-\dfrac{2}{a^2}\left[x\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]-\dfrac{2}{a^3}\bigg[e^{-ax}\bigg]\end{array}$

Thus $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\left[-x^2\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]_0^t-\dfrac{2}{a^2}\left[x\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]_0^t-\dfrac{2}{a^3}\bigg[e^{-ax}\bigg]_0^t=0-\left(-\dfrac{2}{a^3}\right)=\dfrac{2}{a^3}$$

With $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\lim_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}}{x^{\beta}}=+\infty\quad (\alpha>0)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the integral explicitly using Integration by parts just by remembering that $\exp(-x)\rightarrow0\  as\  x\rightarrow\infty$ more fastly then any polynomial going towards infinity, hence it means that $\{x^a*\exp(-x)\rightarrow0\ as\ x\rightarrow \infty\}$ whenever $\text a>0$.

Now the problem just reduced to applying integration by parts thrice and you will get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n>0$. Then, 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{p(x)}{e^x}
$$
is indeterminate. And by L'Hopital's apply $n$ times we have 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{p(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}}{\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a}{e^x}=0
$$
where $a$ is the coefficient on the order $n$ term of $p(x)$.

Comment: L'Hospital rule ?? Why not write $|p(x)| \le C (1+|x|^n)$  and use that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{2^n} = 0$ ?

Comment: @reuns indeed, there are multiple ways to prove this fact

Comment: Clearly l'Hospital rule at $\infty$ is not the easiest way.

Comment: @reuns ah well as long as it's clear

Comment: By the way, how do you know n/2^n tends to zero?

Comment: As $n+2 < 2n$ we obtain $\frac{n+2}{2^{n+2}} < \frac{1}{2} \frac{n}{2^n}$ and $\frac{n+2k}{2^{n+2k}} < \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{n}{2^n}$

Comment: Or lhopital's which is fairly intuitive and involves no tricks

Comment: I don't agree at all. What tricks ? Also, did you prove this l'Hospital rule at $\infty$ ?

Comment: Yea I have. You don't think it's intuitive to compare the derivatives of functions to see which grows faster?

Comment: No. What is intuitive is that if $f(0) = f'(0) = g(0) = g'(0) = 0, g''(0) \ne 0$ and $f''(0)$ exists then $\frac{f''(0)}{g''(0)} =  \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) / x^2}{\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) / x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Comment: Ok, I think I'm done having the typical and pointless argument over what is more intuitive

Comment: I'm talking of proofs. You didn't prove the result after 5 comments. It is obvious the OP won't prove l'Hospital rule at $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$\large (a\ne 0)\quad x^{b}e^{-a x} = e^{-ax+\ln x^b}=e^{u(x)}$

with $\large u(x)= -ax+b\ln x=-ax\left(1-\dfrac{b\ln x}{ax}\right)\sim_{+\infty}-ax$ because $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}{x}=0 $

Thus $$\Large x^{b}e^{-a x} \underset{+\infty}{\sim}e^{-ax}$$